# Getting REACT App running on port 3001 to show on AWS EC2 Http port 80

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I deployed a REACT application on an AWS EC2 running Ubuntu by cloning my github repository and installing node and npm. I tried running the application after installing all of the dependencies and it finally says:
Project is running at http://localhost:3001/

How do I make the running project show up on the http(80) port of the EC2?
Inbound ports open: 80, 443 and 22.

Comment: do you have webserver installed and running ?? e.g. nginx

Comment: no. It's a frontend-only client side project. Do I still need Nginx installed?

Comment: actually you can do that without nginx as well, but for that you need to use some additional package like [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) or [mp2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2), which will do the webserver work for you

Comment: Do you really want to use EC2 for this? Why not use S3 as described in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/WebsiteHosting.html

Comment: @boolfalse I tried. It says "Project is running at http://localhost:3001/" but when I go to http://EC2_PUBLIC_IP:3001/, there is nothing there.

Comment: that 3001 port is not the port you are trying to get from your browser. it just internal port. for that you need to connect the external port to the internal. search for "nodejs reverse proxy"

Comment: sorry, but for now I don't have much time for step-by-step explanation, but anyway, on first try you may see [this](https://www.tecmint.com/nginx-as-reverse-proxy-for-nodejs-app/), I think this could help you

Answer (score 1):

Please install nginx on your EC2 instance which will serve your frontend.

Follow the below blog for steps

https://dev.to/xarala221/the-easiest-way-to-deploy-a-react-web-application-2l8a

Thanks